# How I can filter a Xml File with a Attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, active-directory

hi I want to control a xml file... for this i use linq to xml.

```
private string GetGroup(string xml, string id) 
        {
            XDocument document;
            XElement element;

            try
            {
                document = XDocument.Load(xml);
                //element = document.Root.Elements("Permissiongroup").FirstOrDefault(e => e.Element("id").Value == id);

                element = document.Elements("Permissiongroup").FirstOrDefault(e => e.Element("id").Value == id);

                if (element != null)
                {
                    return element.Element("display").Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally 
            {
                document = null;
                element = null;
            }

        }
```

here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<Permissiongroup>
  <Permission id="Hessen" display="KV-IT" />
  <Permission id="Berlin" display="DBG_Update" />
</Permissiongroup>
```

For example i want if the method is ..

```
string group = GetGroup(xmlpath, "Hessen");
```

group is "KV-IT"

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly are you saying? Does this code not work?

Comment: Did u mean there is some data in xml u want to get data in your program, if that is so ..i know an easy way to do it

Comment: I have the id and I want the display value for this id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a few things wrong with what you currently have - you're missing Permission from the query and looking for an element instead of an attribute.  The following works, albeit I would split it down to check for the existence of elements (e.g. make sure there is a Permission element, etc.) rather than relying on error handling.

```
// string group = GetGroup(xmlpath, "Hessen"); // returns KV-IT
// string group2 = GetGroup(xmlpath, "Berlin"); //DBG_Update

private string GetGroup(string xml, string id)
{
    XDocument document;
    XElement element;

    try
    {
        document = XDocument.Load(xml);

        element = document.Elements("Permissiongroup").Elements(("Permission")).FirstOrDefault(t => t.Attribute("id").Value == id);

        if (element != null)
        {
            return element.Attribute("display").Value;
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        document = null;
        element = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use method Attribute() instead of using Element() to access attributes

```
private string GetGroup(string xml, string id) 
    {
        XDocument document;
        XElement element;

        try
        {
            document = XDocument.Load(xml);
            //element = document.Root.Elements("Permissiongroup").FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == id);

            element = document.Elements("Permissiongroup").FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == id);

            if (element != null)
            {
                return element.Attribute("display").Value;
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally 
        {
            document = null;
            element = null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your xml structure and then can convert xml in to xsd using 
                                                                            http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html#ad-output.

Once you have xsd file , you can download jaxb ,which will convert xsd file in to POJO file

and then in your program you can access attributes of an xml like this

```
  JAXBContext jc2 = JAXBContext.newInstance(someclassname.class);
  File xml2 = new File(xml_File);
  Unmarshaller unmarshaller2 = jc2.createUnmarshaller();
  someclassnameObject= (someclassname) unmarshaller2.unmarshal(xml2);
```

and can use object to use its attributes e.g someclassnameObject.attribute